# How to set the folder conditionally in Sublime Text 2

Tags: json, settings, sublimetext2

I work on two computers where the fullpath of the working folders are different. My current settings file is as follows:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "fullpath_to_working_folder",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want this folder to be changed when I switch to my other machine. I would be happy if there were a way to write an if statement but I don't know how to do it. Any recommendations?

Comment: I suppose some part of your path is exactly same on both computers you want to use, isn't it? You can write the path relatively to the `.sublime-workspace` file location. Could it be the solution?

Comment: Yes, the latter parts are the same. My dropbox folders are different on my machines and the former parts are different. I checked it but don't know how to do that in workspace file.

Comment: Could be exactly as you already have; only instead of `fullpath_to_working_folder` put the relative path. It should be relative to the workspace file location so the path should start with the directory contained in the same folder as your workspace file. Does it work for you?

Comment: That's awesome. I don't know why I didn't think about it! Please provide this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped you! Ok I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the latter part of your path is exactly same on both of computers you use: It is also possible to use relative paths in your `.sublime-workspace` file (instead of full paths) as described in the [doc](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html):

> The path may be relative to the project directory, or a fully
>   qualified path.

You can use it exactly as you already have; just only put the relative path instead of `fullpath_to_working_folder` (better to say there is one redundant comma but perhaps it's typo).

You can also use `name` setting, `file_exclude_patterns` setting and so on ...